# Why do my variables not go out of scope?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

Good afternoon all,

I was taught that when a function returns, The variables (within the scope of that function) automatically go out of scope so we do not have to set them to null.

However, this doesn't seem to be true.

I have a test code that creates a [java.lang.ref.PhantomReference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/PhantomReference.html) pointing to an instance of a [java.lang.Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html). The only strong reference to that object is within the scope of a function F.

In other words, when that function returns, there should no longer be any strong reference to that object, and the object should now be collectible by the the GC.

However, no matter how hard I try to starve the JVM of memory, the GC simply refuses to collect the object. What is surprising is that if I set the variable to null (`obj = null;`), the GC now collects the object.

What is the explanation behind this oddity?

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // currently testing on a 64-bit HotSpot Server VM, but the other JVMs should probably have the same behavior for this use case
        Test test = new Test();
        test.F(new Object());
    }

    public <T> void F(T obj) {
        java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue<T> ref_queue = new java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue<T>();
        java.lang.ref.PhantomReference<T> ref = new java.lang.ref.PhantomReference<T>(obj, ref_queue); // if this line isn't an assignment, the GC wouldn't collect the object no matter how hard I force it to 
        obj = null; // if this line is removed, the GC wouldn't collect the object no matter how hard I force it to
        StartPollingRef(ref_queue);
        GoOom();
    }

    private <T> void StartPollingRef(final java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue<T> ref_queue) {
        new java.lang.Thread(new java.lang.Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Removing..");
                boolean removed = false;
                while (!removed) {
                    try {
                        ref_queue.remove();
                        removed = true;
                        System.out.println("Removed.");
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) { // ignore
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    private void GoOom() {
        try {
            int len = (int) java.lang.Math.min(java.lang.Integer.MAX_VALUE, Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory());
            Object[] arr = new Object[len];
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            // System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A standards-compliant JVM is never *obligated* to collect memory. That is to say, you cannot write a program whose correctness depends on a particular bit of memory being collected at a certain time: you can neither force the JVM to collect (even via `System.gc()`!) nor rely on it doing so.

So, the behavior you're observing cannot, definitionally, be wrong: you're purposefully trying to make the environment do something it is under no onus to do.

That all said, your issue is that your object has not gone out of scope. It is created in `main`, then passed - in the normal Java referential manner - to `F`. Until `F` returns, the `T obj` name is still a reference to your object.

Make `goOom` static and put a call to it in `main`, and you should see the object get collected. But, then again, you might still not, and that wouldn't be *wrong*...

Comment: This makes destructors a complete botch-up as far as language design errors go.

Comment: @Borealid However isn't the whole point of java.lang.ref.PhantomReference such that we can be informed whenever an object leaves the heap? Wouldn't an *arrogant* (for a lack of a better word) JVM render the entire class useless?

Comment: +1, and just to clarify, a weak reference is generally enqueued when the GC determines that it *can* be GCed, whereas the phantom reference is enqueued when the GC takes the next step and actually GCs it. That's a bit vague and not fully accurate; see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ref/package-summary.html#reachability) for a more precise definition.

Comment: @Pacerier Yes, it very well might. It's not a perfect state of affairs. Note the language from the Java spec: "at that time or at some later time" the reference will be enqueued...

Comment: @Borealid Have tried make GoOom static and calling it from well.. *everywhere*, but still no signs of the GC collecting the object (unless the variable is set to null that is).

Comment: @Pacerier Have you tried creating it somewhere other than in `main`? I'm honestly not sure what the rules are about anonymous objects' scoping with respect to the frame in which they were instantiated. But, again, you can't *make* the GC happen...

Comment: @Borealid Btw is it true to say that the presence (or absence) of `obj = null;` shouldn't (and doesn't) affect the *correctness* of the program?

Comment: @Pacerier I'm not exactly sure what you mean. Assigning `null` to `obj` effectively removes a reference - the one inside `F`, to the thing which was named `obj` when the function was invoked. That's why I suggested you let `F` return before you attempted to force a GC cycle - you contended that removing the reference is affecting the behavior you see.

Comment: @Borealid Ic, I meant it in the other way: Is it true that for ReferenceQueue to work correctly, we must keep a reference to the ReferenceQueue and the PhantomReference itself?

Comment: @Pacerier Yes, but that doesn't matter, because the references *within* the `ReferenceQueue` aren't strong.